# ConoHa APIでデータをリクエスト時のエラー

Tags: python, api

サーバーを提供しているconohaでAPIを利用しようと試みておりますが躓いております。
やりたいことはAPIを利用したサーバーの追加です。調べたところ下の手順で作るものだと思われます。
1.トークン発行　https://www.conoha.jp/docs/identity-post_tokens.html
2.　VM追加　https://www.conoha.jp/docs/compute-create_vm.html

1のサイトにあったparametersをrequestに付与してリクエストした際404 bad requestエラーが出たので間違いをご指摘いただけないでしょうか。APIを初めて利用するので何か基本的なことが間違えているかもしれないです。エンドポイントなどは問題ありません。

import requests
import json

def main() -> None: 
url = 'https://identity.tyo1.conoha.io/v2.0/tokens' 
data={"username": "aaa", "password": "bbb","tenantId":"ccc"}
res = requests.post(url=url, params=data) 
print(res.status_code)
print(res.json())

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/119605

Answer (score 1):

https://www.conoha.jp/docs/identity-post_tokens.html　には、
Json形式の文字列　(例として　'{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username":"ConoHa","password":"paSSword123456#$%"},"tenantId":"487727e3921d44e3bfe7ebb337bf085e"}}' という文字列が使われています) をデータとして送るように書かれています。

質問のコードでは、連想配列（{"username": "aaa", "password": "bbb","tenantId":"ccc"}）を送ろうとしています。

bad requestエラーになる原因の一部は、この点だと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Json形式で送ってみたらできました><
Request Paramtersと書かれた所は何を意味しているのか分かりました？てっきりパラメータ付与して送るものだと思っておりましたが.....たとえば下のAPIではrequest jsonの記載がなくrequest parameters のみとなっているため使い方に手間取っております。
https://www.conoha.jp/docs/compute-get_flavors_list.html